# Answer own question

Tags: support, answers, self-answer

I have found an answer by myself to my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67169548/txt-file-function-read-write-position). Do I post the answer as an "Answer" or edit the question? and how to I mark it as answered?

Comment: You should [add an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) Short answer: Post as an answer; you can accept your own answer just like any other (albeit 48hrs after asking the question).

Comment: @41686d6564 zcoop98 has provided me with the post that helped me with my enquiry. thank you for your help nonetheless 

Comment: By the way, thank you for doing a self answer! We like to call them canonicals, and they are incredibly useful.

Comment: @10Rep of course. It might help someone is some way. I have had a lot of help from this website and community, and would love to do the same for others.

Comment: @10Rep A canonical is not the same thing as a self-answer.

Comment: @khelwood but in this case, it's a question, with an answer made by the person. Isn't that a canonical?

Comment: @10Rep A canonical is a well-written question and answer that can be used to dupe-close lots of questions about a certain category of problem. Nothing to do with being self-answered.

Comment: @khelwood ahh ok, thanks for the clarification. But self answered questions can still be helpful, IMO.